# Unable to serve css files placed in src/main/resources/static/css/ folder to client in Spring boot application

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, netbeans

I know this has been posted too many times but I'm still facing this issue. css files placed in static/css folders are not being served to client during get requests.

I'm getting net::ERR_ABORTED 404 on client side with only jsp content being rendered.

I'm using Spring boot 2.1.4 and Netbeans 9.0

Here is the project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

jsp code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Admin Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an absolute path. Change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The problem is I have changed the context-path for the application and the browser is unable to resolve the path for static content.

I had to prefix the href with "/{context-path}/css/styles.css" instead of "css/styles.css".